# How do I find the attribute image in vc_single_image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

Suppose I have a footer that is writen in shortcode with visual compose and I wanna put an image:

```
[vc_single_image image="8469" img_size="full" alignment="center"]
```

where do I find the image value 8469?

Answer (score 7):

You can go to your WP admin and go to Media.

Click the image you want to use. It should open up in a Modal with the image on one side and details on the other. when this happens the url of the page changes to something like:

`/wp-admin/upload.php?item=180`

Or if it opens up in its own page then you will see link like: `/wp-admin/post.php?post=180&action=edit`.

Where **180** is the image's `id` stored in the database. Which is exactly what you need to replace in your shortcode's `image` attribute

Answer (score 2):

go to media library from side menu and select the image you want to insert. The url look `like wp-admin/upload.php?item=4499`
Put the value of the item (in image url) in the `vc_single_image` component
which look like

```
[vc_single_image image="4499"  img_size="200*200" alignment="center"]
```

Answer (score 0):

on a dashboard, go-to media library then select an image click on edit more details than on a Permalink you will get the id of that image